# Mongodb: merge multiple collections in one

Tags: javascript, mongodb, robo3t

I'm quite new with mongoDB; I have 3 copies of a collection in 3 different places (web hosting), and each of these have similar entries, but not equal, like this:

```
database A

Collection "companies":

company1 {
id:...
name:...
...
users: [
{
 username: alpha
 ...
 },
{
 username: beta
 ...
 },
{
 username: gamma
 ...
 }
]

}

database B 
Collection "companies":

company1 {
id:...
name:...
...
users: [
{
 username: alpha
 ...
 },
{
 username: gamma
 ...
 }
]

}

database C
Collection "companies":

company1 {
id:...
name:...
...
users: [
{
 username: alpha
 ...
 },
{
 username: delta
 ...
 },
{
 username: yota
 ...
 }
]

}
```

My question is: is there a way to merge them all, and ask in case of choice (eg: username alpha in db A has "name":"john", in db B has "name" : "Rick") ?

I need to do this with a mongoDB manager, robomongo, Studio 3T for mongodb, or with a script in javascript.

Comment: Can't you just search in the tree databases and merge the results in case of positive at any of them?

Comment: "ask in case of choice" is definitely not a built-in feature, so "script in javascript" is a way to go. I would export/import collections to the same database using different collection names to simplify merge.